# Unknown Gab on tableView

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

enter image description here

[image]

i don't know why my tableView has a unknown gab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set. uncheck `Adjust scroll View Insets` by selecting view controller's from storyboard. Like following screenshot:

[image]

If your storyboard VC added TopBar controller and that `Adjust scroll View Insets` are checked then it will adjust automatically see the following different with checked and uncheck

If `Adjust scroll View Insets` Checked:

[image]

If `Adjust scroll View Insets` Unchecked:

[image]

Comment: how did you know ?? @nitinGohel

Comment: i was facing that same issue before and solve by this. :)

Comment: do you have a discord account ?

Comment: in other project i did check it but it did not effect anything why ??

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: as i told you that navigationController make effect and because of it if we checked the adjust scrollview then xocde manage it self.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137634/discussion-between-nitin-gohel-and-yu-on).

Comment: sorry for late reply Nitin Gohel.

Comment: add me on Discord leonyuon#4170 .